# how to disable Firefox's app tab glow?

Tags: macos, firefox, tabs, css

I recently switched from Linux to Mac OS X, and one little tweak that didn't survive is disabling the blue highlight "glow" that Firefox adds to App Tabs when they have updates. Any idea how to do that?

I followed [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/271512/can-the-glow-notification-on-firefox-4s-app-tabs-be-disabled) to disable it on Linux, but they don't work on Mac OS X. I have this in my `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/personal/chrome/userChrome.css` file:

```
.tabbrowser-tab[pinned][titlechanged]:not([selected="true"]) {
    background-image: none !important;
    background: none !important;
}
```

...but no luck. Putting other CSS rules in that file does work though.

I'm on Firefox 19.0 on Mountain Lion (10.8.2).

Comment: It seems, I found correct place, but can't reproduce glow effect at all. Can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put one of these snippets in your [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css) file, depending on your Firefox version:

#### Firefox 69

Toggle `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` in about:config as well as userChrome.css modification.

#### Firefox 29 (Australis)

```
.tabbrowser-tab[pinned][titlechanged]:not([selected="true"]) > .tab-stack > .tab-content {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

#### Pre-29

```
#tabbrowser-tabs > .tabbrowser-tab > .tab-stack > .tab-background * {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Discovered by looking for `[titlechanged]` selectors in browser.css (chrome://browser/skin/browser.css).

1. https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html
2. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1541233

Comment: i was able to use those to write a `userChrome.css` setting that works. i've added it to your answer; please accept that edit when you get a chance. thanks again!!!

Comment: updated again to handle all parts of the glow. (some had still been showing for the last few firefox releases.)

Comment: `.tabbrowser-tab > .tab-stack > .tab-content[pinned][titlechanged]:not([visuallyselected="true"]) {` as of FireFox 44 (at least)

Comment: Had adapted this answer to `.tab.pinned { background-image: none !important; }` but it doesn't appear to work anymore as of FF 64.0.